# Hyperbolic or spherical analogue to the quadrilateral inequality

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry

This is a reference request.

Let $x, y, z, w \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then we have a so-called "quadrilateral inequality":
$$
0 \leq \lVert x-y-z+w \rVert^2 = \lVert x-y\rVert^2 + \lVert z-w \rVert^2 + \lVert x-z \rVert^2 + \lVert y-w \rVert^2 - \lVert x-w \rVert^2 - \lVert y-z \rVert^2.
$$
Thinking the right-hand side of this inequality as an expression in terms of the Euclidean metric, allows us to write a similar expression for a general metric space $(X, d)$.
$$
0 \leq  d(x,y)^2 + d(z,w)^2 + d(x,z)^2 + d(y,w)^2 - d(x,w)^2 - d(y,z)^2.
$$
If the above condition is satisfied for all quadruples of points $x, y, z, w \in X$, space $X$ is said to have (Enflo's) roundness of $2$. I've heard about the [result](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00013-009-0057-9) that if $X$ is geodesic and of roundness $2$, then $X$ is a CAT(0) space.

---

### Question

Because of the mentioned result about the CAT(0) spaces I'm wondering if there is an analogue to the quadrilateral inequality in hyperbolic or spherical geometry (or, more generally, in CAT(k) spaces).

Comment: Berg and Nikolaev have several papers about it; it includes the corresponding inequality for general k, but the formula is not that nice.